# Optimalization of function which compare two multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I wonder if there is any faster way of finding differences between two multidimensional arrays. By differences I mean (from perspective of `array1`)

how many rows are in `array1` and in `array2`

[image]
<sub>(source: [matematyka.pl](https://www.matematyka.pl/public/zbiory/iloczyn.png))</sub>

how many rows are in `array1` and they are not in `array2`
[image]

and vice versa how many rows are in `array2` and are not in `array1`.

Solution I tried is iterate through both arrays and compare columns. But the fact that those arrays have about `7 columns` it made it pretty annoying.

Is there any use for functions like `array_diff` or something like this?

Comment: If these are arrays built from database queries, you could probably use a database query to get that information

Comment: In the matter of fact they are. However I'm not so good in creating SQL querries and I though it will be easier making it in php script :)

Comment: It's likely to be a lot more efficient doing this in SQL, especially if your tables are properly indexed.... show the SQL to execute the two queries that you have at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Use for first query

```
$comonarray=array_intersect(A,B);
```

you can find comon values in both arrays

By using below function you can find the values only in A array

```
$onlyina=array_diff(A,B);
```

By using below function you can find the values only in B array

```
$onlyinb= array_diff(B,A);
```

Answer (score 0):

## SQL method:

================

### 1) Inner Join:

> returns rows when there is a match in both tables.

[image]

```
SELECT `columns` FROM A
INNER JOIN B
ON A.id = B.id;
```

### 2) Left Outer Join:

> returns set of records only in Table A, but not in Table B and with
>   the WHERE clause exclude the records from Table B

[image]

```
SELECT `columns` FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B 
ON A.id = B.id
WHERE B.id IS null;
```

### 3) Right Outer Join:

> returns set of records only in Table B, but not in Table A and with
>   the WHERE clause exclude the records from Table A

[image]

```
SELECT `columns` FROM A
RIGHT OUTER JOIN B 
ON A.id = B.id
WHERE A.id IS null;
```

---

## PHP method:

================

### 1) Intersecting values:

To find matching values from *array1* and *array2*, use [array_intersect().](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

```
$arr1 = array('a','b','c');
$arr2 = array('b','c','f');

$result = array_intersect($arr1,$arr2);
```

#### Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
)
```

### 2) First array values:

To find values in *array1* not present in *array2*, use [array_diff()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) `array_diff()` takes multiple array parameters but the array to be checked against, should be first.

```
$arr1 = array('a','b','c');
$arr2 = array('b','c','f');

$result = array_diff($arr1,$arr2);
```

#### Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
)
```

### 3) Second array values:

This method also uses the [array_diff()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php), just that we will flip the order of searching. *array2* would come first so that we find values in *array2* that are not present in *array1*.
To find values in *array1* not present in *array2*, use

```
$arr1 = array('a','b','c');
$arr2 = array('b','c','f');

$result = array_diff($arr1,$arr2);
```

#### Output:

```
Array
(
    [2] => f
)
```